# Does fopen call CreateFile on Windows?

Tags: file-io, fopen, libc, createfile, kernel32

From what I know `CreateFile` is found in `kernel32.dll`, and `fopen` is found in `libc`. Assuming for this question they are both being used for file operations, does `fopen` call `CreateFile` on Windows or is it its own standalone file io function with its own code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fopen()` calls `CreateFile()`.
I debugged into `fopen` before and ended up in `CreateFile`.  Unless something changed (which I doubt).. it would still be that way.

I also found this on osr:
https://community.osr.com/discussion/119538